# How to check only the last time a value is added to the table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I am currently writing a code for a database that simulates the work of a library.

I have a table that describes the borrowing of books. The table has
entries like this:

| user_id | book_name | date_borrowed | date_returned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 'Animal Farm' | 2020-02-03 | 2020-02-25 |
| 03 | 'To kill a Mockingbird' | 2020-04-05 | 2020-04-07 |
| 05 | 'Animal Farm' | 2020-03-01 | null |
| 01 | 'Cather in the rye' | 2020-02-01 | null |

I am supposed to create a view which only gives back the books that are free.

I have written this block of code for the view:

```
create view free_books as
select book_name
from book_borrowing
where date_borrowed < date_returned 
and date_returned is not null
with check option
```

When I select all from the table book_borrowing the expected output is:

| book_name |
| --- |
| 'To kill a Mockingbird' |

But the output that I am getting is:

| book_name |
| --- |
| 'Animal Farm' |
| 'To kill a Mockingbird' |

I tried to first put it only to have one row with each book name so there are no two rows with the same book name but that has only been a temporary solution as I need to allow a single book to be entered into the table multiple times for every time it is borrowed. I thought that maybe it was the not null condition that needed to be added but it still looks at the rows before it.

How do I only get the last time that 'Animal Farm' is entered into the table so I can get the expected output?

Comment: What you have selected is all books that have at some point been returned. What you really want is all-books EXCEPT those books that have been checked out and not yet returned. So first, I suggest that you prepare a query that identifies all books still checked out. Then prepare a query that selects all books where book_name not in (Select book_name from check-out-books).

Comment: A flaw in a design that only pulls data from the borrowing table is that it will never select books that have never been borrowed. Do you also have a table of all books?

Comment: Do you not have a *Books* table? I would have thought a more logical design would have a *Borrowing* table in which you record the BookId, UserId, Out and Return dates, then your list of free books is all Books where there does not exist a row in the Borrowing table where there is no return date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (probably) have a table of all books in your library, in which case use it - however you can simulate that from your sample data using the following CTE.

Then it's simply a case of checking that a book does not exist in the *Borrowing* table where its returned date is NULL (ie it's still borrowed):

```
with Books as (
    select distinct book_name
    from Borrowing
)
select Book_Name 
from Books b
where not exists (
    select * from Borrowing r
    where r.book_name = b.book_name 
      and r.date_returned is null
);
```

If you have a proper *Books* table you would do the correlation using its ID (Primary key) since you may have several copies of popular books which you'd need to track by ID, not by Name.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all that `date_returned is not null` is not necessary; if date_returned *is* null then the `date_borrowed < date_returned` will fail and those records will be excluded anyway.

But the main thing here is to add a correlated subquery to consider *only* the most recent date_borrowed record.  So you need to change your Where clause to

```
Where date_borrowed=
    (Select max(date_borrowed)
     From book_borrowing x
     Where book_borrowing.book_name=x.book_name
    ) and date_borrowed < date_returned
```

You should also use an alias on your outer book_borrowing table reference and use it inside the subquery.